# Rails migration cannot find a result and fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

My rails migration is failing because of the following line:

```
username = User.find(user_id)
if (!username.nil?)
    ...
```

I have a user_id of 100 which has no matching user in Users so username is returning as nil (I think) but then my entire migration crashes

I thought that the if (!username.nil?) would overcome this... is there another way to not crash upon no results in find()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If [`find`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find) cannot find the record with the id you specify then it raises an `ActiveRecord::NotFoundError` exception.

If you want to return `nil` when there is no such record you can do:

```
username = User.where(id: user_id).first
```

(and note that it is a `User` instance and not the name of the user)